# Conventions for dimensions of input and weight matrices in neural networks?

Tags: neural-network, matrix

Im currently learning neural networks and I see conflicting decsriptions of the dimensions of weight and input matrices on the internet. I just wanted to know if there is some convention which more people use than the other.

I currently define my input matrix X with the dimensions of:

(m x n)

Where m is the number of samples and n is the number of features.

And I define my weight matrices with the dimensions:

(a x b)

Where a is the number of neurons in the layer and b is the number of neurons in the last layer.

Is that conventional or should I change something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not say there is such a convention for it per se (if anyone has anything to comment on this, I would also like to know).

I think to make it clearer how the layer's input `x` interacts with the weights `W`, it might better to define the dimensions as the following:

- `x`: (m x n)
- `W`: (n x k)
- bias term `b`: (k)

m remains as the number of examples. n represents number of input features and k represents number of neutrons in the layer.

As we know, we compute the output of the layer `y` as `Wx + b`. Therefore, the resulting output matrix will be  (m x k)

Comment: Thanks! Guess I will switch to that notation for the weight matrices since I saw that one on the Internet too. I always thought it's a bit complicated since if we want to multiply W by X we have to write (W.T @ X.T).T to get a (m x k) output.

Comment: Or just do X @ W, however that differs from most formulas I saw on the internet.